# Terminal Hangs when running bot

Tags: linux, scripting, python, nohup

I have a bot installed on my Azure Linux VM running Ubuntu 18.04. I am running the command to start my bot, and it returns an error (see below). The console freezes as well apparently because it allows no other commands to be run.

```
$ nohup python3 bot.py > nohup_bot.out

nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

Comment: do you just need that command to be placed in the background?

Comment: Actually it's not an error, just a message from nohup. If you want this to run in background, `nohup python3 bot.py > nohup_bot.out &`.